# Minimal Distance Between a geometry and a layer on PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, multipoint, st-distance, polygon-to-point

I am working on PostGIS where I have a two tables.
Let's call them A and B.
A is coming from a multi polygons layer.
B is coming from a multi points layer.

I have created a new column "min_distance" in A. I would like this column to take the value of the distance between the current polygon (eg the own of the row) and the closest point in the table B.

I am thinking about a "for" loop and using the ST_Distance() function but I am honestly lost about how to implement it.
My question is : How can I do this ?

By the way, I am also searching for a clear tutorial about PostgreSQL programing.